# Optimal Windows C tool stack

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, gcc, compiler-construction

I am planning a bigger C-only project. It should run on both Linux and Windows. My question is, what is the optimal development stack (compiler, IDE) on Windows? Problem is, we would like to use C99 (if possible).
On Linux it's quite easy because usually combination GCC+VIM+GIT is optimal. But on Windows?

I am concerning: `Visual Studio 2010` (no C99 support), `MinGW` and `Intel C++ Compiler`.

How do they compare with each other in terms of performance?

Comment: Wait a sec, you're asking about performance and also mentioning Vim and Git?  Your editor and source control system don't affect performance of your compiled code.  Are you asking about the performance of the tools (compile time, etc.) or the quality of the generated code?

Comment: I am asking for whole stack. Second criterion is performance of compiled code.

Comment: @James: Then you've got two questions... ask about the best optimizing compiler first (that'll be Intel, most likely), and then once you pick that, about a recommended IDE for driving it.

Comment: you can use GCC, VIM and git on windows via cygwin; unless you're looking for something suitable for "people used to working on windows" in which case I guess that's irrelevant.

Comment: This is highly subjective. Vim may be "optimal" (whatever that means) for you, but it isn't for many others.

Comment: tehwalrus: you don't need a full-blown POSIX emulator to run vim. Only a bit for git, but that's hopefully going to change once libgit2 gets a client app.

Comment: MinGW with a compatible IDE works fine, from my experience. VS has some really nice stuff to it, but it's not strictly necessary, especially if you're doing a C-only project. ...Actually, I think you might be able to customize VS to utilize MinGW, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @JAB: Using VS with GCC is shooting yourself in the foot, really. Just use any of the *other* great IDEs that properly support the GCC toolset.

Comment: Are you writing a desktop app, a game, or a server?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IDE, I've happily used  VC++, MonoDevelop, and Code::Blocks (the latter two are cross-platform, as a plus).  C isn't a very difficult language to make an IDE for, so most anything will work and it'll just come down to personal preference.

For compiler... C is very quick to compile on all of them, so I guess by performance you mean of generated code?

In my experience, Intel C++ optimizes best if you're targeting Intel CPUs.  MinGW GCC optimizes best for everything else.  VC++ optimizes very good, but not quite as much as GCC or ICC.  This is of course in the general sense only -- I've had plenty experiences where VC++ bests them both.

VC++ compiler can integrate with some non-VC++ IDEs, like Code::Blocks.  As you said, lacks C99 support (though, it does have stdint.h).

MinGW integrates with most IDEs, except VC++.  Once upon a time its port of libstdc++ lacked support for wchar_t, making Unicode apps very difficult to write.  I'm not sure if this has changed.

ICC integrates with the VC++ IDE, some non-VC++ IDEs, as well as supporting C99 and Linux, however it has been shown in the past to deliberately use sub-optimal code when used with non-Intel CPUs -- I'm not sure if this is still the case.

[Agner Fog](http://www.agner.org/optimize/)'s [Optimizing software in C++](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf) provides a decent comparison of compilers, included optimization capabilities.

Comment: +1 for Code::Blocks. Don't use it much because I don't do many large C projects, but if I did that's what I'd use.

Answer (score 1):

Well, GCC is GCC. Performance is identical over different OSes, minus ABI and C stdlib differences that may impact performance.

This is an easy problem to solve, use GCC everywhere, meaning MinGW, or the more up to date [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) (includes 32 and 64-bit compilation capabilities). It provides all (most, meaning 99.9%) of the Win32 API when you need it.

Note that although it's the same compiler, ABI is different for say, Windows x64 vs Linux x64 (in this case: the size of `long`), and you should ensure the code compiles and works on all platforms you intend to target, regularly.

Using GCC with `-pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra` is a nice help for this (if you silence all warnings!), but not perfect.

The Intel compiler will bring better  performance, but is only free for personal use on Linux (you can't distribute binaries produced by the free version if I remember correctly), so if you want free tools, that's out. Visual C sucks at C99. It's a C89 compiler, and that isn't going to change soon.

Most development tools are available on Windows as well, see for example [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) and [vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php).

Comment: It's a C89 compiler that supports a couple C99 features and has a number of proprietary features of its own. Last I checked the development team was focusing its attention on getting VS compatible with C++0x, I believe?

Comment: @JAB: "it" ? Did you mean, "MSVC is a C89 compiler that ..." ? But yes, Microsoft is chasing C++0x, not C99.

Comment: @JAB: indeed, they said as much as "we won't work on C for the coming years" when MSVC 10.0 was announced. No noteworthy C99 stuff is there (variable-length arrays for starters).

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, that's what I meant. I figured it would be fairly obvious considering that's the only place in the answer where C89 is mentioned.